# Add search bar in sidebar

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I've been searching for a long time, but couldn't find any info on how to add a search bar in the sidebar. I know that adding select list could be done like this :

```
    JHtmlSidebar::addFilter(
        JText::_('JOPTION_SELECT_LANGUAGE'),
        'filter_language',
        JHtml::_('select.options', JHtml::_('contentlanguage.existing', true, true), 'value', 'text', $this->state->get('filter.language'))
    );
```

How about adding text field with search ability ?

Answer (score 0):

That's usually achieved with a form and an

```
<input type="text"
```

box.

You should however consider using one of `mod_search` or `mod_finder` modules, and eventually override their templates to achieve the look and feel that you want.

Both modules are shipped with Joomla and include configuration parameters and leverage Joomla native search functionality.

Comment: Are you talking about frontend ? I'm talking about backend.

Comment: In the backend, you can create a simple html form that points to your (custom) component.  Add backend to the question, I didn't pick it up.